# Change Cell CSS Datatables based on content

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

in jQuery Datatables I want to make validation of AJAX data visible, when parsing Excel Data.

When generating data in PHP, I add (!) for a warning or (!!) for an error to the values in my dynamic (both columns and rows) table.

Once the table is loaded, I want to change the background-color of these cells when the cell-data contains (!) or (!!).

Anyone got a clue how to fix this? Looping through all cell data and adjust cell background color for the warnings (orange) of errors (red).

I tried fnRowCallBack, but cannot figure out how to verify if cell-data contains (!) or (!!). Maybe using Regex?

Any help should be really appreciated,

Goal:

[image: example]

```
$("#tableDiv").empty();
$("#tableDiv").append('<table id="displayTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead></table>');
$('#displayTable').dataTable({
  "data": json.data,
  "pageLength": 200,                            
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback:

```js
var tableHeaders = '<td>name</td><td>zipcode</td><td>country</td><td>telephone</td>';
var json = {data: [
    [ "name1", "zipcode1", "country1", "telephone1"],
    [ "name2", "zipcode2", "country2(!)", "telephone2"],
    [ "name3", "zipcode3(!!)", "country3", "telephone3(!!)"]]};
$("#tableDiv").empty();
$("#tableDiv").append('<table id="displayTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead></table>');
$('#displayTable').dataTable({
    "data": json.data,
    "pageLength": 200,
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        data.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
            var i = ele.indexOf('(!!)');
            if (i > -1) {
                row.querySelectorAll('td')[idx].classList.add('red');
            } else {
                i = ele.indexOf('(!)')
                if (i > -1) {
                    row.querySelectorAll('td')[idx].classList.add('yellow');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: that's great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each td in your table and read the content of td tag to check if contains (!) or (!!) and change background color of that td accordingly. This is basic implementation. This can be improved further for better performance, but it will get you going with your requirements

```
 $("#tableId tbody tr td").each(function() {
    if($(this).html().indexOf("(!)") !== -1) {
      $(this).css("background-color","orange");
    } else if($(this).html().indexOf("(!!)") !== -1) {
      $(this).css("background-color","red");
    }
  });
```